# Call to a member function bind() on a non-object in

Tags: forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

my action.class.php

```
 if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == sfRequest::GET) {
                 $this->formShoppingList = new ShoppingListForm(array(
                        'shoppinglist' => $items,
                            ), array('shoppinglist_id' => $list_id));
}

    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $this->formShoppingList->bind($request->getParameter('shoppinglist'));
     print_r($this->fromShoppingList;
    }
```

My lib/ShoppingListForm.php:

```
<?php

class ShoppingListForm extends BaseForm {

public function configure() {
    $shoppinglist_id = $this->getOption('shoppinglist_id');

    $this->setWidgets(array(
        'shoppinglist' => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(array(), array('rows' => '10', 'cols' => '35')),
        'action_id' => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(array()),
        'list_id' => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(array(),array('value' => $shoppinglist_id)),
    ));

    $this->widgetSchema->setLabels(array(
        'shoppinglist' => '',
    ));


    $this->setValidators(array(
        'shoppinglist' => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 5000), array(
            'required' => 'ShoppingList is empty.'

        )),

        'action_id' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false)),
        'list_id' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false))

    ));

    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('shoppinglist[%s]');

    gfFormHelper::addRequiredToLabel($this);
}

}

?>
```

When I submit the form, the error is coming up:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind() on a non-object in....
>
> Tampa-Data:
>       shoppinglist%5Bshoppinglist%5D=liste+15%0D%0A
>       shoppinglist%5Baction_id%5D=1
>       shoppinglist%5Blist_id%5D=15

Why? Solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a instance of the `ShoppingListForm` before you `bind` it :

```
if ($request->isMethod('post'))
{
   // Create instance of ShoppingListForm here
    $this->formShoppingList = new ShoppingListForm();
    $this->formShoppingList->bind($request->getParameter('shoppinglist'));
    if ($this->formShoppingList->isValid())
    {
    // do something with the submitted data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You only create the form if the request is GET, and only bind it if the request is POST. There's your problem: if it's a post, the form hasn't been instantiated, therefore $this->formShoppingList is null.